# python request how to send \u instead of \\u

Tags: python

demo

```py
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
payload = {r"\u005F\u005F\u0069\u006E\u0069\u0074\u005F\u005F": {}}
res = requests.post(url + '/register', json=payload)
```

The request data is always modified to `\\u005F\\u005F\\u0069\\u006E\\u0069\\u0074\\u005F\\u005F`

I don't want `\` to become `\\`

[image]

Comment: You are sending a string that contains actual backslash characters; double backslashes are exactly how they *must* be represented in JSON.  But why are those backslashes there in the first place?  There is no need for any sort of Unicode escaping for this data, all of those characters are ordinary ASCII that require no special handling.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals :

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
> letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat
> backslashes as literal characters. As a result, in string literals,
> '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially.

The `r` at the start of the string specifies this is a "raw" string, so `\u005F` is not an unicode character, but 6 characters: `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `5` and `F`, see:

```
>>> a = r'\u005F'
>>> len(a)
6
>>> print(a)
\u005F
```

If you want to use `\uXXXXX` as an unicode characters, you can't use `r` at the start of the string, then the `\uXXXX` codes are translated into proper unicode characters, see:

```
>>> b = '\u005F'
>>> len(b)
1
>>> print(b)
_
```

So in your case - just remove the `r` at the start of the sting and it should work.